# How can i set the value of my textbox using radio button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2012

this is my controller view

```
public ActionResult rb()
    {
        subject ts = new subject();
        ts.subjectlist = db.tbSubjs.ToList();
        ts.selectsubj = "";
        return View(ts);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult rb(subject sj, FormCollection frm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var selectsubj = sj.selectsubj;
            string getcode = frm["subj"];
            ViewBag.ssss = getcode;
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

and this is my class

```
public class subject
{
    public List<tbSubj> subjectlist { get; set; }
    public string selectsubj { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code for the radio button

```
<div style="text-align: left">
@using (Html.BeginForm("rb", "Home"))
{ 
<div>------</div>
foreach (var ts in Model.subjectlist)
{ 
<div>
    @Html.Label(ts.SubjCode)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.subjectlist, ts.SubjCode)
</div>
}

foreach (var getsubj in Model.subjectlist)
{ 
    <div>------------------</div>
<div>
    @getsubj.SubjCode
    @Html.RadioButton("subj", getsubj.SubjCode)
</div>
}
<br />
<input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
</div>
```

and i want to set a value in my textbox in this view by getting the value of my radio button.

```
@model ATM.Models.subject

@{
ViewBag.Title = "rb";
}

<h2>rb</h2>

@Html.TextBox(m => m.selectsubj)
```

If someone is willing to help me please help me.

Comment: For clarity's sake, are you going from one view, with the form, to another view, with the textbox? Or is this all on the same view?

Comment: I am going to another view sir

Comment: OK, so are you meaning to use `ViewBag.ssss` to pass said value between the views? If you're not married to that idea, you could simply pass it in via the `ATM.Models.subject` model that the second view is based on. Either way, if this is what you're trying to do, I can add an appropriate answer, just let me know.

Comment: can you show me the answer in your way sir?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your action actually looks more like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult rb(subject sj, FormCollection frm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var selectsubj = sj.selectsubj;
        string getcode = frm["subj"];
        ViewBag.ssss = getcode;

        return View("view_with_textbox");
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

You could do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult rb(subject sj, FormCollection frm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var selectsubj = sj.selectsubj;
        string getcode = frm["subj"];

        var model = new ATM.Models.subject()
        {
            selectsubj = getcode
        };

        return View("view_with_textbox", model);
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

Thereby passing the value in via the model.

Comment: One more question sir. How can i put it in my textbox in view? Sorry I am not familiar in mvc

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't tried it yet, but by passing in a model with the value, and then using it on a View that declares that model at the top with `@model`, it exposes the value automatically to any inputs that use that model property, like  `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.selectsubj)`